# WPF: Load Window inside Grid frame

Tags: wpf, grid, window

I have `WPF` application and `ListBoxItems` as right Menu.

When specific `ListBoxItem` Islected i want to load different `Window` that i created called **Home** (instead of create several `Grid` elements and changed its `Visibility`) so i have this Grid:

```
<Grid>
     <Frame Name="MyFrame"/>
</Grid>
```

And when the specific `ListBoxItem` `Islected`:

```
MyFrame.Content = new Home();
```

And got this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: ''MyApplication.Home' root element
>   is not valid for navigation.

'

Is this the right way to load other Window/`Page` ?

Answer (score 1):

`Home` must be a `Page` or a `UserControl`. You can't set the `Content` property of a `Frame` to an instance of a `Window`.

If you want navigation history, you should consider using the `NavigationService` of the `Frame` to navigate to a page:

```
MyFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Home.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: What is the different between Window and Page ?

Comment: Well, it's two different types. A window is a floating *top-level* thing only. It cannot be the child of any other element.

Comment: So if i want to load every ListBoxItem different Window with elements can i use Page as well ?

Comment: You can set the `Content` property of the `Frame` to a `Page` that contains whatever you want to display.

Comment: i want to register to my ListBox SelectionChanged event and i have 3 ListBoxItems and 3 pages and every index will how different Page, whan show specific Page what to do with the Current Page that need to Disappear ?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Your original question was about how to load a window into a frame and this is not possible.